# Mantain column names in map function with table

Tags: r, purrr

I have the following data stored in the object HRdata:

```
            ï..Employee_Name       PositionID              Position State  Zip
      1:   Adinolfi, Wilson  K         19  Production Technician I    MA 1960
      2: Ait Sidi, Karthikeyan         27                  Sr. DBA    MA 2148
      3:     Akinkuolie, Sarah         20 Production Technician II    MA 1810
      4:          Alagbe,Trina         19  Production Technician I    MA 1886
      5:       Anderson, Carol         19  Production Technician I    MA 2169
     ---                                                                     
    307:        Woodson, Jason         20 Production Technician II    MA 1810
    308:     Ybarra, Catherine         19  Production Technician I    MA 2458
    309:      Zamora, Jennifer          6                      CIO    MA 2067
    310:           Zhou, Julia          9             Data Analyst    MA 2148
    311:         Zima, Colleen         19  Production Technician I    MA 1730
```

I am using a map function to table the unique instances in each variable within the data.frame.

```
HRtables <- map(tibble(HRdata), ~as.data.frame(sort(table(.x), decreasing = T, responseName = "n")))
```

It makes a list just fine but the output is not to my liking:

```
    > HRtables$State
   .x Freq
1  MA  276
2  CT    6
3  TX    3
4  VT    2
5  AL    1
6  AZ    1
7  CA    1
8  CO    1
9  FL    1
10 GA    1
11 ID    1
12 IN    1
13 KY    1
```

Is there any way I can keep the original name of the variable instead of it being replaced with .x?

Comment: Would you, or have you considered or tried to solve the problem using dplyr? I.e. using functions like arrange instead of sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could pass in the column `names` of your data.frame using `map2`. Then you could include `dnn` argument for `table` that would include the column name. Perhaps something like this might work for you.

```
library(tidyverse)

map2(HRdata,
     names(HRdata),
     ~as_tibble(sort(table(.x, dnn = .y), decreasing = T)))
```